# header location redirect not working

Tags: php, redirect

I have got a login page and upon successful login I redirect either to the page where the user came from or to index.php. This worked nicely until I implemented ajax to login. The problem is that after successful login the page redirects to the same page not to the index. it just redirects there and shows the index.php page inside the login.php

The url looks like `localhost/login.php?/index.php`

js

```
$('.login').on('click', function() { 
var user = $('.username').val();
var pass = $('.password').val();
ref;//redirect url
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "process.php",
data: {req: 'req', user: user, pass:pass, ref:ref},
cache: false,
success: function(response)
{  
}
});

});
```

process.php  I am getting every value from the js but the redirect doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
if(isset(_GET['req'])){ 
if(empty($_GET['user'])){
echo "uname empty";
}
else if(empty($_GET['pass'])){
echo "pass empty";
}
else{
if(...){
//some validations
}
else{
//everything good...redirect to index.php or user's page
 $page = $_GET['ref'];
if(!empty($page)){     
//Redirect to the page where user came from
header("location: ".$page);
}
else{header("location:index.php");}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Redirecting an AJAX request is somewhat pointless. Either submit the request normally using a form or use JavaScript in the success callback to redirect once the AJAX request succeeded (in that case you probably want to return some sort of status code).


And for the sake of everything that's holy to you: **It is UNACCEPTABLE to submit a login form via GET. That causes passwords to show up in server logs. ALWAYS use POST!**

Comment: @FerozAkbar done it but nothing has changed.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Okay changed it to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this

```
$page = $_GET['ref'];
if(!empty($page)){     
//Redirect to the page where user came from
echo $page;
}
else{echo 'index.php';}
}
```

and in ajax response

```
success: function(response)
{  
  location.href='/'+response;
}
```